# Best way to phrase this?

Tags: grammar, writing

1. He grabs the dead cop's legs and drags him away.
2. He grabs the legs of the dead cop and drags him away.
3. He grabs the dead cop by the legs and drags him away.

Are all these correct? What is the best way to phrase it?

Comment: I really hope this is for a story you are writing and not for "real life"

Comment: Just a story, don't worry.

Comment: The question is really about proofreading, something we don't do on this site (or, at least, we are not supposed to). Which of them do you think works best, and why?

Comment: I think #3, if it's grammatical. But would like to know what would be the most natural way to write it.

Comment: I would agree with you; but it isn't really the purpose of this site to help you with your creative writing.